# Java initialize object using string and reflection

Tags: java, reflection

My program will serialize an instance of a class called Configuration. 
First, take keys values of the atributes from a configuration txt file like:

```
SECONDS=60 
NAME=JINGGLE 
LIFE=true
```

So, before serialize, I must to take this key values and translate to the instance:

```
for(Entry<String, String> entry : attributes.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();

            Field field = c.getDeclaredField(key);
            field.setAccessible(true);

            try {
                        //Get the data type and transform the string to this type
                        Class<?> type = field.getType();
                        Object atribute ;
                        atribute = type.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(value);


                        field.set(o, atribute);
```

This works, for example, with Strings and Integers, but no for primitive values or booleans... 
How can I do for instance a boolean using reflection and getting the valor with a string like true or false? Or how do it with primitive values int.

Comment: You can get the class object for primitive types either using `int.class` or `Integer.TYPE`. It's similar for the other primitives.

Comment: So, simply don't use primitive classes? Instead use object classes? Boolean instead boolean?

Comment: No, use primitives when appropriate. But if you want to find a constructor, that accepts a primitive parameter, pass the correct class instance. To find a constructor that uses a single int param, do `type.getConstructor(Integer.TYPE)` or `type.getConstructor(int.class)`

Comment: No, the problem is that the paramater alwais will come from a string. For example, seconds="60". Si programatically i want to fins the attribute seconds, is int type, and set their valour to 60. So, how can I put int secons = "60" or bool life ="true"

Comment: Maybe I'm not undestanding you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primitive types don't work well through reflection using Field since there is no constructor for primitives..

If you know the primitive type you expect for a given field use the class version of parse then cast to the primitive after parsing (either explicit or  implicit).

You'll need to do this by name and have a lookup table of expected strings and types (or an if/elseif block to check the input string).
Example:

```
if (key.toUpperCase().equals("SECONDS"))
{
    int seconds = Integer.parseInt(value);
    //set field value (using an overload with primitives or explicity
}
```

Comment: The problem is if I don't know what "atributes" i'm loading. I mean, I want this class like a generic for different configuration files of different programs. So I'll never know when I will have a parameter with int or bool... So the solution is in this cases not  use primitives

Comment: A little late, but you can do something like "java.lang.Integer:property=value" which will contain it's class type, then read it in using reflection to create the instance of the class. In short though, yes primitives won't work when you don't know what your expecting unless you limit the primitive to a single type that every expected input except strings can be cast to.